# OSX - always hide certain files

Tags: macos, terminal

I know how to show and hide hidden files in the Terminal - but is there a way to hide certain files like .DS_STORE when showing hidden files? Make certain files super-hidden, so to speak?

Comment: You want to hide them when doing "ls" in the terminal or in Finder?

Comment: I want to hide them in the Finder

Comment: there is now way to hide them globally other than by finding them all and adding the hidden flag

Answer (score 8):

Use `chflags` with the hidden option

ie: `chflags hidden fileToHide` to hide the file from the Finde

and `chflags nohidden fileToHide` to show the file

Please do keep in mind the warning in man page:

> Only a limited number of utilities are chflags aware.  Some of these tools include ls(1), cp(1), find(1), install(1), dump(8), and restore(8).  In particular a tool which is not currently chflags aware is the pax(1) utility.

What that means is that while you won't see in the Finder or Open/Save dialog boxes, the Terminal will still see it and possibly other programs that don't respect BSD flags.

Answer (score 3):

To follow up on @ibz's answer, an alias would work fine, but you may want to make a shell script that takes parameters for a little more flexibility.

```
#!/bin/bash

/bin/ls $@ | grep -v .DS_Store
```

Create the above in ~/bin and name it `lv`, chmod 755 on it, and remember to add ~/bin to your path in your .bash_profile

```
export PATH=~/bin:$PATH
```

You can also name it `ls` as long as you put ~/bin first in your PATH and use the full path to /bin/ls in your script so that you don't get recursive interpretation.  Whenever you want to use the real `ls`, then you'll need to specify the full path.

Answer (score 2):

To follow up on @tvanfosson's answer, a script would work fine, but you can make it simpler by defining a function in your .bashrc. :)

```
function lv { ls $@ | grep -v .DS_Store; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this in your .bashrc

```
alias lv="ls -al | grep -v .DS_Store"
```

Now use lv instead of ls to see all the files (including hidden), but excluding .DS_Store.