# Show all hidden files except .DS_Store

Tags: macos

I know I can do [this](http://osxdaily.com/2009/02/25/show-hidden-files-in-os-x/) to show all hidden files in Finder.  It's very helpful but I would prefer to pretend that .DS_Store did not exist.  Can I hide only that file?

Answer (score 1):

even if your question is quite old it's not outdated yet.

Sadly it seems that there is **no** satisfying solution for hiding just the `.DS_Store` files in OSX.
But if you want to hide them in your terminal/console view here we have one solution: [OSX - always hide certain files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393868/osx-always-hide-certain-files)